# Umbraco - two websites on single Umbraco instance - 2nd site gives 404

Tags: web, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, umbraco

I've set up two Umbraco websites on a single instance of Umbraco (v 4.7.1.1). If I visit the 1st website (which is listed first under the 'content' node):

www.mysite.com

... I get the correct homepage (the homepage is nested at content > www.mysite.com > Global > homepage)

However when I go to the 2nd website (listed directly under the 'content' node, below the 1st website):

m.mysite.com

... I get a 404. The homepage for the site is nested the same way (content > m.mysite.com > Global > homepage), and I can get to the homepage by using the address m.mysite.com/global/homepage. I've checked/tried the following:

- The 'Manage hostnames' configuration for both sites in Umbraco is correct
- I have useDomainPrefixes set to true in my umbracoSettings.config
- There are no redirects in my IIS 7.5 that are redirecting the 2nd domain name
- My bindings are correctly set up in IIS
- the default document in my IIS 7.5 for my Umbraco instance is set to default.aspx. I've moved it to the top of the list
- The hosts file on the web server is pointing m.mysite.com to the correct IP
- the homepage for my 2nd site is using a template
- Tried adding a property to the doctype that's used by the root node for the 2nd 'website', with alias 'umbracoRedirect' and type 'content picker', and pointing the node to my homepage (apparently this method can have problems anyway, even if it works)
- I've tried adding a property to the doctype that's used by the 'Global' node, with alias 'umbracoInternalRedirectId' and type 'content picker', and pointing the node to my homepage
- Tried adding a property to the doctype that's used by the 'Global' node, with alias 'umbracoRedirect' and type 'content picker', and pointing the node to my homepage (apparently this method can have problems anyway, even if it works)
- Tried putting a homepage for my 2nd site directly below the root node of the 2nd site (although the 'Link to document' for this page comes up as m.mysite.dev/test/)
- Tried adding an umbracoInternalRedirectId to the website node itself, to point to the new homepage directly below the root website node
- Tried an iisreset and then flushing my DNS resolver cache, the site still gives a 404
- Tried fully republishing both websites
- Separately re-published all nodes in the 2nd website, and separately published the new homepage I created immediately below the site root node
- Edited the web.config file
- double-checked everything, tried re-applying 'Manage hostnames' configuration, tried re-doing the 'umbracoInternalRedirectId', republishing the site and restarting IIS again

Comment: How about if you create this identical setup on your local dev machine? Using your local hosts file.

Comment: Have you tried the XmlContentCheckForDiskChanges setting in umbracoSettings.config, umbraco has two levels of caching and it just loads one from the other so it can be a pain the change hostnames once they are there.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in the physical folder structure for the Umbraco installation there's a file config\UrlRewriting that contains the following:

```
destinationUrl="~/global/en"

rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"

ignoreCase="true"/>
```

So if I change things so that the page I want to be my homepage for the mobile site is the page 'en' in the following structure:

Site 2

- global

  - en

It works, since m.*mysite*.com now points to my page at `http://m.*mysite*.com/global/en`.

Here's are the original steps I needed to get this working:

- add A-record to my domain for host 'm' (ie. m.*mysite*.com)
- right click m.*mysite*.com Umbraco site > Manage hostnames - add m.*mysite*.com
- add binding to the umbraco website, for m.*mysite*.com
- edit umbracoSettings.config (in W3Cms\config) - set  to true
- may need to restart IIS for settings to take effect